# Load data from BigQuery to Snowflake

Tags: google-bigquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My data is in Big Query now I have to load data from Big  Query to Snowflake. So Here like to know that how can we do that in Google by using which service we can do that.

If there is any help document that will be great help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try this ? Is it working ? What is the approach you used ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 basic options

1. Write the data out to Google Storage and load it into Snowflake using its standard COPY INTO command
2. Use a tool that can read data from BQ and write to Snowflake - whether that’s a specific ETL tool or a general coding tool like Python